# Is there a Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion theorem for positive roots of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems

Simple question by one that I have not found an answer for.

> Is there a theorem like the Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion, but tells if me if all the roots of a polynomial are positive?

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you are looking for. Is [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) relevant?

Comment: I know about sturm's theorem. What I am looking for is a proof that has already been done for the case of determining if all the roots of a polynomial are positive.

Comment: i.e. What are the conditions for the polynomial $a_n x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ to have all positive roots.

Comment: So why doesn't Sturm's theorem answer you question?

Comment: I know that it does. I am asking if there is a special case like Routh-Hurwitz theorem that covers my case.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AzJ `a special case like Routh-Hurwitz theorem` You could use Routh-Hurwitz for $P(-z)\,$.